# T-SQL - what happens if am looping through cursor and at the same time an insert into the table happens?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

Consider this. I have a table called dbo.Event.

I declare a cursor for it:

```
declare myCur cursor for 
    select a from dbo.event
```

Then I:

```
open myCur
fetch next from myCur into @temp
while @@fetschstatus = 0
    ...
    do the job using fetched value
    ...
fetch next from myCur into @temp
end
```

The question is - myCur needs some time to loop through all available values which we had in table at the moment when cursor fired. What happens when cursor is till running BUT the insert happens into dbo.Event. Will already running cursor pick up this new inserted value and iterate over it too? Or by the end of the cursor execution newly inserted values won't be processed by cursor?

Comment: Rule #1 about cursors: **avoid them** if ever possible!

Comment: @marc_s I know it :) The issue is that I have a legacy code and I need to figure out WHY it haven't worked (if the problem is in code itself or in smth different). So unfortunately I need to clarify this.

Comment: If you have legacy code that you need to analyze this closely it seems like an excellent opportunity to get rid of the cursor in the legacy code.

Comment: Yes. Only if you are a developer authorized to change code on client's paltform and not an implementation engineer who needs to find the root cause of a problem and report it to dev team. Now I am not even sure that my problem caused by coursor - answer on original question will clarify it.

Comment: I a pretty certain that the default option for a cursor is `DYNAMIC` therefore modifications to the base data are reflected in the cursor. If you want specific behaviour, explicitly state it, e.g. `DECLARE A CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FAST_FORWARD FOR...` Don't rely on defaults. You can check the properties after declaration using `SELECT properties FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid);`, It sounds like you want a snapshot of the data when the cursor opened so you should be using a static cursor.

Comment: But you original question does not have an answer.   Without an order by there is not set order.

Comment: @GarethD thank you, I googled static vs dynamic cursor, you are right - it reflects changes in underlying data automatically (upon a fetch). Please put it as answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I a pretty certain that the default option for a cursor is DYNAMIC therefore modifications to the base data are reflected in the cursor. If you want specific behaviour, explicitly state it rather than relying on default behaviour, e.g.

```
DECLARE A CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FAST_FORWARD 
FOR...
```

You can check the properties after declaration using:

```
SELECT properties 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@spid);
```

It sounds like you want a snapshot of the data when the cursor opened so you should be using a static cursor.

Comment: See the doc, "SCROLL_LOCKS cannot be specified if FAST_FORWARD or STATIC is also specified."